# How to save a layer file with a relative path

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vba

In VBA, how do you save a layer file (.lyr) with a relative path?

I have some code that loads a shapefile into ArcMap but I am unsure of how I go about using this shapefile to then save a layer file to disk that has a relative path set.

The idea is after I have run my code and output all the layer files I can move the shapefiles and their associated layer files from a local drive which I use for processing my data to another location where other people can use it.

Answer (score 5):

This topic has been discussed before on the ESRI forum, see below.

[Export lyr to relative path](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=266149)

> The issue that you can't go higher in the file hierarchy is really
>   annoying.
>
> But there is a difference when you save the layer via ArcMap:
>
> Make sure that "Store relative path names to data sources" is active.
>
> Rightclick a layer in the TOC, choose "Save as Layer File...") and
>   store the .lyr on your disk.
>
> The Layer is stored in a binary lyr-File. Open the lyr-File with a
>   simple texteditor (e.g. Windows-Notepad).
>
> You can find out the path to the data source stored in the lyr file.
>
> For Example:  . . \ . . \ . . \ . . \ d a t a b a s e \ T e s t . g d
>   b
>
> That means that relative from the lyr-File the data source is four
>   folders higher then folder database and there Test.gdb.
>
> If you save the lyr-File with ArcObjects the following path is stored:
>   d a t a b a s e \ T e s t . g d b
>
> It's the incorrect path to datasource.
>
> Why can't I save the lyr-File with the correct relative path to
>   datasource?
>
> I used the following code (C#) to save the lyr-file:

```
private void saveLyr(string lyrFileName, IFeatureLayer pFLayer)
        {
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lyrFileName)) return;
                if (pFLayer == null) return;

                //Layer ermitteln
                IDataLayer2 pDataLayer = pFLayer as IDataLayer2;

                IName pname = pDataLayer.DataSourceName;
                IDatasetName2 datasetName = pname as IDatasetName2;
                IWorkspaceName workspaceName = datasetName.WorkspaceName;

                string pathToDB = Path.GetDirectoryName(workspaceName.PathName);

                pDataLayer.RelativeBase = pathToDB;

                saveToLayerFile(lyrFileName, pDataLayer as ILayer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void saveToLayerFile(string layerFilePath, ILayer layer)
        {
            try
            {
                if (layer == null) return;

                //create a new LayerFile instance
                ILayerFile layerFile = new LayerFileClass();

                //make sure that the layer file name is valid
                if (Path.GetExtension(layerFilePath) != ".lyr")
                    return;
                if (layerFile.get_IsPresent(layerFilePath))
                    File.Delete(layerFilePath);

                //create a new layer file
                layerFile.New(layerFilePath);

                //attach the layer file with the actual layer
                layerFile.ReplaceContents(layer);

                //save the layer file
                layerFile.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```